# JavaScript PDF: Null and Undefined issues

Tags: javascript, pdf, null, undefined

I have JavaScript in a PDF. I have a button that takes multiple form field responses, applies some rules, and then fills in another form field.

The only issue I'm having is a null and undefined one. For example, there's a dialog that pops up and asks for an input and stores it in the variable **cResponse1**.

However, when the response is null or undefined, I can't get the form to fill.

My code is basically this, to fill the final field, on a button mouse up::

```js
this.getField("Notes").value = "Some words and "+stmt_cRepsonse1+" stuff.";
```

I've tried filling the variable **stmt_cResponse1** using a switch to get around the null and undefined issues.

```js
switch(cResponse1) { // x
   case null: 
   var stmt_cResponse1 = "";
  break;
   case undefined: 
   var stmt_cResponse1 = "";
  break;
   case "": 
   var stmt_cResponse1 = "";
  break;
   case "null": 
   var stmt_cResponse1 = "";
  break;
   case "undefined": 
   var stmt_cResponse1 = "";
  break;
   case " ": 
   var stmt_cResponse1 = "";
  break;
   default: 
   var stmt_cResponse1 = ""+cResponse1+"";      
}
```

So basically, my code works if I put something into the dialog and thus have some characters stored in cResponse1. I need the variables to remain when the document is saved, closed and re-opened.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statement could work, except you're defining the variable `stmt_cResponse1` inside of the switch statement, so you can't access it outside of the statement. You should define the variable above the switch statement and then set its value accordingly in the cases

Comment: I'm no JavaScript pro as you can see. So you're saying i should have something like:

var stmt_cResponse1 = cResponse1

And then do the switch?

Comment: Yeah or you can just declare the variable with `var stmt_cResponse1;` and then do the switch but without the `var` keywords so that you don't redeclare the variable

Comment: So something like this:
    
var stmt_cResponse1;
switch(cResponse1) { // x
   case null: 
   stmt_cResponse1 = "";
  break;
   case undefined: 
   stmt_cResponse1 = "";
  break;
   case "": 
   stmt_cResponse1 = "";
  break;
   case "null": 
   stmt_cResponse1 = "";
  break;
   case "undefined": 
   stmt_cResponse1 = "";
  break;
   case " ": 
   stmt_cResponse1 = "";
  break;
   default: 
}
`code`

Comment: @minnesota73 What prints out when you try executing that code?

Comment: It's in a PDF and not a JavaScript console. But I click the button, nothing fills to the form field. If I click the dialog, the area where I enter information that becomes cResponse1 says "undefined" in it. So long as it says that, it won't fill the form field. If I change that any character, it will then fill in the field.

Comment: @minnesota73 ah I missed that part. I've never used JavaScript in a PDF like that before so I'm not sure what the issue is